# Replacing notebook thermal pads

Tags: gpu, cooling, acer-aspire, laptop-repair, thermal-pads

I happen to own 2 Acer Aspire notebooks - old 5737Z and newer V3-571G. One thing they have in common is overheating a lot (I wouldn't blame them, they were abused a lot). I heard it could help quite a lot to replace standard thermal pads with copper ones. My questions are:

What dimensions should the pads be? I disassemblied the older computer a few times and the old ones seemed quite thick, so how about something like:
http://www.dx.com/p/heatsink-thermal-copper-plate-pad-for-hp-dv2000-hp-dv3000-hp-dv9000-more-10-piece-pack-132949#.VDUrF_l_t8E ?

What about the other one (never opened it before)?

Should I do this? Is it safe? I am quite comfortable messing with electronics in general, but inserting loose pieces of metal into a computer feels a bit adventurous.

If yes to above, how do I do this? I reckon just spread thermal grease both sides and stick it in place, right?

Comment: the dimensions depend on the specific hardware.  If you don't know what you are doing you really shouldn't mess with it.  Laptops are design with very specific thermal designs.

Comment: the better word for those is "shims" as pads suggests the thermal pads. sarching e-bay for shims with the laptops model number might get you some hits for approx sizes used. Finding guides done already by others, or having a selection to pick from. the "pads" cope with a whole lot of offset and bad angles and even different heights from similar items. replacing with shims and thermal paste is some crafting not all science :-)  I hate pads but know why they are there.  You probably want to use a "thicker" thermal paste, and you should be prepared to install fresh Normal pads where needed.

Comment: This isn't about not knowing what I'm doing - I already did some notebook repairs myself and everything was always fine (or at least not more broken). It's about being a reasonable guy who tries to do some research (preferably from people that do this kind of thing every day) before sticking own hands into hornets' nest.

Comment: @Psycogeek thank you, this was actually very helpful. English is not my primary language, so I do struggle with tech nomenclature sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

Wehter you should do this is up to you and how you judge your abilities. It is safe (for you) when you remove the battery from your laptop. Whether it is safe for your laptop is again up to your abilities.

<strike>I think there is a misunderstanding here. What you posted in your question is a thermal pad. They are used instead of thermal paste for heat dissipation not in combination! You could remove the old pad and replace it with paste.</strike>

Unfortunatly I have no experience with pads. I always used paste. There are many pastes available, from cheap to enthusiast grade. But even the most enthusiast grade paste will give you maybe only a 5°C difference compared to a cheap one. But more expensive paste has the feature to be spread more easily.

Which one is the right for you is hard to say but you could read [this](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/thermal-paste-performance-benchmark,3616.html)

If you use pad or paste is also up to you but don't apply paste if you are going to use a pad!

On how to do this: No, one does not apply on both side paste. The method I use and which is also wide spread is to place a rise corn big drop in the center of the chip and let pressure of the heatsink do the spreading. There are thousands of videos on YouTube with different methods.

**In case you decide to use paste: I highly recommend you to not use any liquid metal paste!** They have the best heat dissipation but removine the paste again will require a grinding machine.

Edit: You didn't mention at all what your temperatures actually. Normally laptop CPUs and GPUs are made to withstand a higher temperature compared to a desktop. Maybe it wouldn't be even worth it to replace the pads.

Comment: This is no misunderstanding, I didn't mean standard silicone-based pads, but solid copper ones instead. The point is to fill the gap that could be too wide for just a thick layer of thermal paste, with something of much better thermal conductance. The temperetures are high enough to cause ocassional restarts/bluescreens.

Comment: I see. I actually never heard of those before. Sorry for that then. Judging by the picture those pads seem very thick and to get good head dissipaton one would have to apply paste on the CPU and on the heatsink. I say this would restrict the heat dissipation. I recommend you to use paste only and have the cpu direct contact to the heaetsink for best performance.

Comment: Hold on a second. What is the point of those then? If paste needs to be applied on both sides, you are just adding copper between CPU and heatsink. Just another material which will probably worsen your temperatures. If this is actual solid copper paste needs to be applied.

Comment: Well, If you need an academic dispute about this, here you go. According to wikipedia, copper has approx. 400 times better thermal conductivity than your usual silver-based thermal grease. Of course you need some paste in order not to have air between elements, but it will be just a thin layer, while rest of the space is filled with copper.

Comment: And if you think hard enough, you will come to conclusion that it's not a coincidence that radiators are more often made of copper rather than of thermal grease! :)

Comment: So? Heatsinks are made of copper! You are adding an extra layer of copper between the CPU and the copper of the heat sink which again, will result in worse temperatures and also the need to apply paste onto 2 surfaces. Maybe you should read the link I have provided in my answer. You have said it youself. One does need paste to remove air. What you do is add a solid layer on which you have to apply paste twice then.

Comment: You really wanted me to use Paint, right? Here: http://i.imgur.com/Kt6CRef.png - and what I also said myself, copper deals with heat much better than paste, and it's not 2 or 3 times better but 400.

Comment: OK, last try. YES, copper is better for head dissipation. and heat sinks are made of copper! so it does _NOT_ make any sense to add an extra layer of copper between CPU chip und heat sink. I will avoid any further discussion. Also I don't know why you drew the paste as thick as the copper pad. You only use a tiny, thin layer of paste.

Comment: You may or may not discuss with me any further, but why do you think thermal pads exist in the first place? Why not use thermal grease everywhere? Well, that's because very often (at least with notebooks) for some reasons (valid or not) a _thin_ layer is not enough to fill a gap between the IC and the heat sink. And the amount of space there exists not because of my opinion, but because of how the components are made in a huge Chinese factory. So the method of using only thermal paste you're proposing will very likely result in having nothing but air between radiator and grease covered GPU.